# Agent Docker not execute any sh command

Tags: docker, jenkins

- Computer Mac M1
- Create a Docker image from jenkins 2.355 with Docker Pipeline 1.28

When run a simple agent docker like this:

```
    pipeline {
        agent { docker { image 'node:16.13.1-alpine' } }
        stages {
            stage('build') {
                steps {
                    sh 'node --version'
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

The agent is pull correctly but the sh command is never executed. The jod is freezed and after many seconds the job stoped .

This is the console log obtained:

```
Started by user Miguel Salinas Gancedo
[Pipeline] Start of Pipeline
[Pipeline] node (hide)
Running on Jenkins in /var/jenkins_home/workspace/docker-demo
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] isUnix
[Pipeline] withEnv
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] sh
+ docker inspect -f . node:16.13.1-alpine
.
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // withEnv
[Pipeline] withDockerContainer
Jenkins does not seem to be running inside a container
$ docker run -t -d -u 0:0 -w /var/jenkins_home/workspace/docker-demo -v /var/jenkins_home/workspace/docker-demo:/var/jenkins_home/workspace/docker-demo:rw,z -v /var/jenkins_home/workspace/docker-demo@tmp:/var/jenkins_home/workspace/docker-demo@tmp:rw,z -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** node:16.13.1-alpine cat
$ docker top 71f7d4d760e80490e325446e445050b46558b45e0ca4c3a99ef9ac8b65e2666d -eo pid,comm
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] stage
[Pipeline] { (build)
[Pipeline] sh
process apparently never started in /var/jenkins_home/workspace/docker-demo@tmp/durable-f28a3e4d
(running Jenkins temporarily with -Dorg.jenkinsci.plugins.durabletask.BourneShellScript.LAUNCH_DIAGNOSTICS=true might make the problem clearer)
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // stage
[Pipeline] }
$ docker stop --time=1 71f7d4d760e80490e325446e445050b46558b45e0ca4c3a99ef9ac8b65e2666d
$ docker rm -f 71f7d4d760e80490e325446e445050b46558b45e0ca4c3a99ef9ac8b65e2666d
[Pipeline] // withDockerContainer
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // node
[Pipeline] End of Pipeline
ERROR: script returned exit code -2
Finished: FAILURE
```

What is wrong??

Answer (score 0):

following the instructions here in https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/installing/docker/ totally fixed this problem for me. Just remove everything related to your existing Jenkins image, volume etc...and start again from scratch with those instructions.

I guess the new updates have changed the way DinD works with Jenkins.

I hope it works out for you.